# Configuring aws cli use fakes3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Keen to setup fake s3, have it working via [docker setup](https://hub.docker.com/r/lphoward/fake-s3/). Running on port 4569. I cannot figure out how to test using aws cli (version 1.10.6). specifically change the port for the access.

i.e. want to do a command like

```
 $ aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

i need to specify the port, i've tried

- `--port settings on command line`: i.e. `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ignored AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ignored aws s3 --profile fakes3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt` (says not valid parameter)
- `adding a profile and including end_point="localhost:4569` in config in ~/.aws`. gives error about AUTH Key
- running fakes3 on 443 but that then clashes with my local machine

Has anyone got aws cli working with fakes3?

```
 $ aws s3 --version
 aws-cli/1.10.6 Python/2.7.11 Darwin/15.2.0 botocore/1.3.28
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--endpoint-url` argument.  If fakes3 is listening on port 4569, try this:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4569 s3 ls
```